White line showing above the window after using JNA's SetWindowPos() method
I am creating a Java application to rearrange windows using customizable keyboard shortcuts. I am using the JNA 5.14.0 library, specifically the USER32.SetWindowPos() method, to move windows.
The issue I am facing is that a white line appears above the window after moving it. This seems to happen only if the window was maximized when calling the method and if the window is not a Microsoft Windows default application (e.g., File Explorer, Notepad, etc.).
Here is the method body:
private void moveWindow(int windowNewXPosition, int windowNewYPosition) {

    WinDef.HWND currentlyFocusedWindow = USER32.GetForegroundWindow();

    if (currentlyFocusedWindow != null) {

        // check if window is resizable
        int style = USER32.GetWindowLong(currentlyFocusedWindow, WinUser.GWL_STYLE);
        boolean resizable = (style & WinUser.WS_SIZEBOX) != 0;

        if (resizable) {
            USER32.SetWindowPos(
                    currentlyFocusedWindow,  
                    null,  
                    windowNewXPosition, 
                    windowNewYPosition,  
                    WINDOW_WIDTH,  // predefined width
                    WINDOW_HEIGHT,  // predefined height
                    User32.SWP_NOACTIVATE 
            );
        } else {  
            USER32.SetWindowPos(
                    currentlyFocusedWindow,  
                    null,  
                    windowNewXPosition, 
                    windowNewYPosition,  
                    0,  // keep existing width
                    0,  // keep existing height
                    User32.SWP_NOSIZE | User32.SWP_NOACTIVATE
            );
        }
    }
}

Here is the screenshot. Any suggestions on how to prevent this from happening?

I have tried the following:

Experimented with different flags, setting different width and height values
Tested with various applications and noticed that the issue is specific to non-default Microsoft Windows applications
Tried alternative methods like USER32.MoveWindow() but encountered the same issue

